# Reference request: existence of a subgroup of $G(\mathcal O_k)$ that is "uniform" across $P \overline{N}$

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras, reductive-groups, root-systems, buildings

Let $G$ be a connected, reductive group over a $p$-adic field $k$.  Let $P_0$ be a minimal parabolic subgroup of $G$ containing a maximal split torus $A_0$.  Let $K$ be a maximal compact open subgroup of $G$ in good position relative to $P_0$, so we have $G = P_0K$ (if $G$ is unramified, we can take $K$ to be a conjugate of $G(\mathcal O_k)$).

For each standard parabolic $P$, let $M$ be the unique Levi subgroup of $P$ containing $A_0$.

Does there always exist an open subgroup $H$ of $K$ such that we have
$$H = \bigg(\prod\limits_{\alpha \in \Phi(A_M,P)_{\textrm{red}}}(H \cap N_{-\alpha})\bigg)(H \cap M)\bigg(\prod\limits_{\alpha \in \Phi(A_M,P)_{\textrm{red}}}(H \cap N_{\alpha})\bigg)$$?  Here $A_M$ is the split component of $M$, and $N_{\alpha}$ is the product of the root subgroups $U_a$ for $a \in \Phi(A_0,G), a|_{A_M} = \alpha$.

This is claimed in Waldspurger's [notes](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1474748003000082) on the Plancherel measure for $p$-adic groups, based on Harish-Chandra's lectures, Section I.1.
[image]

No proof was given for the existence of $H$.  I was wondering if anyone knew a reference for this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of such subgroups $H$ is proved in section 2, paragraph 2.1 b) (pages 15 and 16) of

*Bernstein, J. N. Le "centre'' de Bernstein. (French) [The Bernstein "center''] Edited by P. Deligne. Travaux en Cours, Representations of reductive groups over a local field, 1–32, Hermann, Paris, 1984.*

More precisely Bernstein proves that there are arbitrary small compact open  subgroups $H$ of $G$ satisfying the product decompositions (i.e. the so called Iwahori decompositions). In particular you can find one in $K$.

Comment: In modern language, the Moy–Prasad subgroups $G_{x, r}$ with $r > 0$, and $x$ lying in the image of the building of $M$, have this property (and form a neighbourhood base at the identity).